# Adding a ID to GMaps.js Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am not using the default google maps, i'm using a package that is supposed to simplify it, called [GMaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/).

I need help on how to add a ID to a GMaps.js Marker, this is what i've got:

```
    map.addMarker({
        lat: 63.998847,
        lng: 11.486882,
        title: 'Test Marker',
        id: 'marker'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case , i think you should use `addControl` method which has DOM id property.

```
var map = new GMaps({
  el : '#basic-map',
  lat: -12.0433,
  lng: -77.0283,
  zoom: 12
});

 map.addControl({
   id: 'marker'
 });
```

**to get specific marker and hide or show**

```
$('#basic-map').gmap('addMarker', { 'tags':'foo', 'position': '42.345573,-71.098326', 'bounds':true });
$('#basic-map').gmap('find', 'markers', { 'property': 'tags', 'value': 'foo' }, function(marker, isFound) {
        if ( isFound ) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
        }
});
```

Comment: This is using the default Google Maps API, i need the solution for GMaps.js.

Comment: i've edited the answer hope this will works for you

Comment: how can i hide the marker with that? cause i need to be able to assign a form for Identification to each of my map markers and then hide them with JQuery toggle();

Comment: $.each(map.markers,function(){this.setMap(null)}); this hides all the markers

Comment: Problem is that i need to hide like 20 diffrent markers. Imagine a button list where one button hides one specific marker.

Comment: Nope, didnt work.. Isn't there a simple var we can use like: class: or id: inside the addMarker(); would be so much easier to just hide it with a div or class.

Comment: you can check [here](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-filtering.html) i think you want to do smth like that

Comment: No i need the refrence for GMaps.js not Original Standard Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

GMaps.js forwards arguments to google.Maps.Marker which accepts a MarkerOptions object specification.

See:   https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps/blob/9a0ad96adc56c004424b17c6cdb7dcc1add94654/lib/gmaps.markers.js#L21

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions

There is no ID option. So whatever you'd like to do needs to be done a different way. E.g. remove all markers to hide, add back the ones that should be visible.

Comment: So there is no option for it in GMaps.js? i need to use google maps standard API?